# Ordering related products by ID (DESC) in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So here's the problem that i ran into. I'm trying to show new products in the related products tab on a WooCommerce Store (WP 4.9.6, WooCommerce 3.3.5), but no matter what i try it returns the very same results, ordering them according to the arguments i have in the array. What i can't seem to make it do, is change the way the query works because it seems to me that it always runs the same thing and gives me the same rows from the database ordered according to my arguments.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', function( $args )  
{ 

$args = wp_parse_args( array('orderby' => 'date','order' => 'DESC','posts_per_page' => 4), $args );
    return $args;

});
```

Comment: Delete all the transit from `wp_options` table (like `_transient_wc_related_70`, `_transient_timeout_wc_related_70` _here 70 is the product ID replace it with your product ID_), then try again. You are getting this because WooCommerce's cashing.

Comment: There is nothing about 'wc_related' in that database table. Do you have any other ideas?